# C# how do you remove a duplicate object in a list - where the object itself is complex and also has lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have a c# list ComplexTypeObj

The class ComplexTypeObj  - has the following 3 properties

Searches = new List (complex object)

Ids= new List (guid type)

Surnames = List (string type)

I need a way to find out if there are duplicate ComplexTypeObj in the list where each of the properties match but I'm having a little trouble with the logic on this one?

Comment: Implement `IEquatable<T>` on your ComplexTypeObj class and use `HashSet.SetEquals` on the lists. etc.

Comment: IEquatable and GetHashcode ;)

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented Iequatable<T> for the equals                                       
 public bool Equals([AllowNull] ComplexTypeObj other)
        {
            return this.Searches .Equals(other.Searches) && 
            this.Ids.Equals(other.Ids) &&
            this.Surnames Equals(other.Surnames);
        }                                                                                                                            how would I use the HashSet.SetEquals?

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill for your purposes, but my favorite library for comparing complex objects is **CompareNETObjects**

(**GitHub**: https://github.com/GregFinzer/Compare-Net-Objects)

(**NuGet**: Install-Package CompareNETObjects -Version 4.73.0)

Here is a .NET Fiddle with a working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vP2ya3

```
    // This is the comparison class
    var compareLogic = new CompareLogic();

    // (Optionally define some configurations for the CompareLogic)
    // e.g. Compare different types, Ignore props, Case sensitivity, etc. 

    compareLogic.Config.IgnoreProperty<ComplexTypeObj>(x => x.Searches);
    compareLogic.Config.TreatStringEmptyAndNullTheSame = true;
    compareLogic.Config.CaseSensitive = true;

    // Compare the results
    var compareResults = compareLogic.Compare(cto3, cto1); // Where the magic happens.
    
    // Check if objects are equal
    if(!compareResults.AreEqual)
    {
      // Do something...
    }
```

But in addition to just checking if they are equal, the `ComparisonResult` object returned will let you view individual differences between object properties or get a string of all property differences just as a few examples.